# two database connection with Mysqldb in python

Tags: python, database, connection, mysql-python

Can any body please let me know if more than one database connection at a time is possible with Mysqldb in python script. I have a scenario where i want to query from databaseA tables (which can be from more than one table using join operation ) and store the resultset into another databaseB table named 'results'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Truly a strange question. You open two connections and work with them independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open two connections and work with them as needed.

Where should be the problem?

Comment: Thanks Sentinel, just i got reference from book Mysql for python by Albert Lukaszewski, very simple book for beginner. Which helped me to get my answer.